# Url rewriting to remove .php causing loops

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite url on my site such that,

1. **www.example.com/login** points to **www.example.com/login.php**
2. **www.example.com/login/** too points to **www.example.com/login.php**
3. Pages deep inside the site should follow the above rule. i.e

   **www.example.com/inner/inner2/something**
   and **www.example.com/inner/inner2/something/** should also point to

   **www.example.com/inner/inner2/inner3/something.php**
4. **www.example.com/login/anything** , if doesn't exist should show 404 *(as in my case it's causing loops)*

The rule I have written is:

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
   RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1.php [L]   
   RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1.php [L]
```

It works fine, in 3 of the above cases but in 4th it's causing loops.

Also I want to show an 404, if a file with .php extension is requested.

And also, the behaviour of above rule changes if I use REQUEST_URI instead of REQUEST_FILENAME. What's the difference between the two?

**TIA**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this rule for php extension hiding:

```
# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: For 404 handling you can use: `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php` and show custom page from `404.php`

Comment: Thanks, but how to show 404 when a page with .php extension is requested.

Comment: Sorry, but it's not working. .php pages are still being displayed. Isn't it possible to refrain people from using .php extension to access pages? I think R=404 is not working. As I read it somewhere that only R=302 or R=301 are supported or may be there's some other reason...

Comment: Ok I got confused by your 404 comment. Check the code now for 301 redirection. It will redirect `/file.php` to `/file`

Comment: Thanks, it works as you described. But, still there's no way to show 404 when .php pages are requested. right? The idea was to stop users from knowing in what language site has been written. Thank you very much, anyways!

Comment: With present rules you can completely hide .php extension. Just have your URLs as `<a href='/user'>User</a>` and it will silently load `/user.php`

Comment: Yups.. I understand that. Thanks again :)